# Memory leak -- setting variable in init?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

Memory management has me confused again --

In my .h file, I have:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableDictionary *properties;
```

In my .m, I have the following init method, which complains of a leak in Instruments on the self.properties line:

```
- (id) init {
  self = [super init];

  self.properties = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

  return self;
}
```

It also complains of a leak if I don't use the accessor.

Likewise, it leaks if I use this strategy:

```
NSMutableDictionary *temp = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

self.properties = temp;

[temp release];
```

And in dealloc I have:

```
self.properties = nil;
[properties release];
```

I thought I was following the rules, but this one is alluding me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your .h is defined like this:

```
@interface MDObject : NSObject {
    NSMutableDictionary *properties;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *properties;

@end
```

The following are possible correct implementations of your .m:

```
@implementation MDObject

- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
         properties = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [properties release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

or

```
@implementation MDObject

- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
         self.properties = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    self.properties = nil; // while this works,
                           // [properties release] is usually preferred
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

It might be helpful to remember that

```
self.properties = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

is the same as

```
[self setProperties:[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]];
```

Those 2 methods that are synthesized for you would look similar to the following:

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *)properties {
    return properties;
}

- (void)setProperties:(NSMutableDictionary *)aProperties {
    [aProperties retain];
    [properties release];
    properties = aProperties;
}
```

Comment: Thanks -- turns out I was being led down a funny path by Instruments -- it wasn't the object I thought that was leaking, but your rules helped remind me of where to really look.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `@property(retain)` then you shouldn't just `alloc` and then use the accessor because you've over-retained the object. Either release it after you set the property or autorelease it first.

Comment: But, shouldn't that have been solved by either not using the accessor (also complains) or my strategy using `temp`, which I then release?

Comment: You are using the accessor in both of your examples.  `self.properties =` uses the accessor; `properties = ` does not.

Comment: Right -- I didn't copy and paste that version, but I did mention "It also complains of a leak if I don't use the accessor" -- I should have been more clear

Comment: You must be doing something else wrong, because it should be fine if you alloc and then just assign it.