# How do I fix this leak while using properties?

Tags: ios, properties, memory-leaks

I am a noob with properties and how to manually release things since I typically use ARC but in this case I am not so I need a little help on how to fix the leak below. Now since it is a property, do I just stick a autorelease on the end or not. I am not sure! :)

Anyway if anyone can tell me how to properly get rid of this leak, that would be great!

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        self.purchasableObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        self.storeObserver = [[ZTStoreObserver alloc] init];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self.storeObserver];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633174/memory-leak-setting-variable-in-init

Comment: Have you used weak properties?

Comment: Which object is leaking?

Comment: storeObserver is leaking. Also I am not using ARC, sorry if that was unclear in the question.

Comment: It turns out all I needed was a autorelease as seen in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024579/setting-property-to-newly-allocd-object-using-accessor-cause-memory-leak

Comment: By the way, you should not use accessor methods like `self.purchasableObjects` in the `init` method. See [Don’t Use Accessor Methods in Initializer Methods and dealloc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW6) in the _Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide._ You should probably do `_purchasableObject = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]`, etc.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `SKPaymentQueue`'s `transactionObserver`, but it's possible that it maintains a strong reference to your `self.storeObserver`. If so, you can always use `removeTransactionObserver` in the `viewWillDisappear` method (but if so, you probably want to move the `addTransactionObserver` to `viewDidAppear`).

Comment: Hmm, but is this the right thing to do: self.storeObserver = [[[ZTStoreObserver alloc] init] autorelease]; ? I am still getting a potential leak of an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed both of the reported leaks:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        self.purchasableObjects = array;
        [array release];

        ZTStoreObserver *observer = [[ZTStoreObserver alloc] init];
        self.storeObserver = observer;
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self.storeObserver];
        [observer release];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shuold use strong, if you dont want to loose them.

```
@property(strong) NSMutableArray *purchasableObjects;
@property(strong) ZTStoreObserver *storeObserver;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume self.purchasableObjects must be strong reference(if it is weak, the memory will not be retained unless, there exist another strong reference to keep this object alive), Then you will not leak memory, but you may find total memory footprint increased, thats called allocation.To keep the memory footprint low, you can set that variable to nil and avoid retain cycles once you are done with that variable.You can probably forget about this variable until you receive a memory warning, at that point you can nil this object to reclaim the memory